# How to make a transition slide from down to up not up to down

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

So basically I got this transition.
At the beginning height is 0 and when you hover the DIV specified height becomes 100px.

it all works smoothly except, the height starts from the top.

How can I make it start from bottom?
this is what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHBVY.gif

So how can i make it slide from down to up?

This is the css I am using for this.

```
.bd-box tr td .bd-name {
    background: rgba(186,0,0,.8);
    width: 100px;
    height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    overflow:  hidden;
}
.bd-box tr td:hover .bd-name {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: add `bottom:0` to `.bd-box tr td .bd-name` and set `td` to `position:relative`

Comment: Can you add a Fiddle or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning and move the element up rather than changing the height.

```
div
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;

    background: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div div
{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

div:hover div
{
    top: 80px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v52j3exv/)